# Gmail filter not finding message containing partial string

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-search, paypal

I'm trying to filter emails from PayPal so that certain *Notification of payment received* messages get forwarded when the transaction's description field (in the message body) contains a specific reference code.

An example transaction description would be `28/10/2023SSSS_JohnSmith`. Gmail finds the message when I search for `2023SSSS_JohnSmith`. I need it to match only on the reference code `SSSS_` to catch all of the right messages, but searching for this shorter string does not return any results.

I've looked at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en and I've tried the following patterns:

```
*SSSS_*
"SSSS_"
"*SSSS_*"
+SSSS_
```

In case the underscore was causing trouble for some reason, I also tried all of the above without it.

As per standard practice, the emails from PayPal have the body encoded in both plaintext and HTML format, and the HTML formatted version uses nested tables for the layout.

Thanks in advance